Svelte $effect rune not logging on array.push for $state rune
This is the code I'm using. Its also in sevelte5 playground here.
What I don't understand is, why it's not logging when I add todo with array.push but works when I do reassignment. However, when I uncomment commented lines in $effect body, it works for both. Just curios if I understand $effect correctly here.
<script>
    let todos = $state([{
        text: "Todo 1",
        status: "pending"
    }]);

    $effect(() => {
        console.log(todos)
        // const countEl = document.getElementById("count");
        // countEl.innerHTML = todos.length
    });

    function pushTodo(event) {
        if (event.key != 'Enter')return
        const elem = event.target
        todos.push({text: elem.value, status: "pending"})
        elem.value = ""
    }
    function spreadTodo(event) {
        if (event.key != 'Enter')return
        const elem = event.target
        todos = [...todos, {text: elem.value, status: "pending"}]
        elem.value = ""
    }
    
</script>

<div class="todos">
    <input onkeyup={pushTodo} placeholder="Push Todo">
    <input onkeyup={spreadTodo} placeholder="Spread Todo">
    <ul>
    {#each todos as todo}
        <li>
            {todo.text}: {todo.status}
        </li>
    {/each}
    </ul>
    <p>Total: <span  id="count"></span></p>
    
</div>


Reactivity in Svelte 5 is fine-grained. If you have an effect that just references an array, that effect will only trigger if the array reference changes, i.e. on reassignment to a different array.
This also means that dummy assignments like todos = todos will not do anything.
If you just want to observe an object for development purposes, use $inspect, which observes the object deeply and also unwraps the state proxy. (Note that $inspect will not be part of the production build.)
If the $effect actually uses any of the array contents, it will also trigger accordingly. E.g. if you JSON.stringify it, all items and their properties are read and hence observed by the effect.
$effect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(todos))
});

push() affects todos.length, so if you read that in the $effect, it will trigger on push() but not if an existing item is modified.
$inspect internally uses $state.snapshot which also can be used in an effect to deeply read the object.

I haven't started to use Svelte 5 yet, but this behavior did for sure surprise me too. Will this be a problem in practice? I imagine the only time one would want to use a variable storing an object/array like this without accessing any nested info from it might be to log it, and for that we can use $inspect(), so in practice it might not be a problem? But all of us that haven't learned to use $inspect(), but uses $effect() with console.log() (like me and Rahul), will be in for a surprise ^^

@PeppeL-G: As you noted, in most cases you will access some of the data and then it will trigger when that data changes. The more realistic issues are usage of async code (dependencies after the first async operation will not be tracked) and creating infinite loops by changing something the effect depends on which is sometimes hard to see.

Using $state.snapshot(todos) will also inspects the object deeply. Docs: https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte/$state#$state.snapshot
